# Orthogonal matrix with non-unit determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, orthogonality

Can I have a matrix $Q$ which is orthogonal because each of the column vectors dot products with each other is 0? Or must only satisfy $QQ^T=I$.  For example consider the following matrix $Q$:

$$Q=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & -2 \\
-2 & 2 & -1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}$$

1. Calculating the dot product of each column pair:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2  \\
-2  \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
1  \\
2 \\
2 
\end{pmatrix}=0 ,\quad \begin{pmatrix}
2  \\
-2  \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
-2  \\
-1 \\
2 
\end{pmatrix}=0 , \quad and \begin{pmatrix}
1  \\
2 \\
2 
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
-2  \\
-1 \\
2 
\end{pmatrix}=0 $$

Suggests all vectors are orthogonal to each other.

2. But $det(Q)=27$ and $QQ^T=9I$.

So is it or is it not orthogonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns are mutually orthogonal but it is not an orthogonal matrix because the columns are not normalized. I agree the terminology is weird.

Comment: Ahhhh, so the vectors themselves have to be orthonormal for the matrix to be orthogonal?

Comment: @HCAI Correct. ${}$

Answer (score 1):

By definition a matrix $Q\in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is orthogonal **if**:

1. $Q$ is invertible.
2. $Q^{T}=Q^{-1}$.

Moreover, we know that $Q\in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is orthogonal **iff** the columns of $Q$ setting a orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

**Remark:**

A set $\beta=\{c_{1},c_{2},\ldots,c_{n}\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a orthonormal basis **iff**:

1. $\beta$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
2. The inner product between $c_{i}$ with $c_{j}$ denoted by $\langle c_{i},c_{j}\rangle$ for $i\not=j$ is zero, i.e., $\langle c_{i},c_{j}\rangle_{i\not=j}=0$.
3. The norm for each $c_{j}\in \beta$ satisfies $||c_{j}||=1$.